# Why can 2 xbee units not discover each other?

Tags: xbee

I have followed the steps outlined [here](http://tutorial.cytron.com.my/2012/03/08/xbee-series-2-point-to-point-communication/) and everything appeared to work 100%.  However, when I open up [X-CTU](http://www.digi.com/support/productdetail?pid=3352&osvid=57&type=utilities) and click "Digi Device Discovery" the two xbee units cannot find each other.

My suspicion is because the coordinator node is on channel and the router has an operating channel "12" whereas the coordinator node has an operating channel "11".

But I am not able to change either of them via the X-CTU GUI.

How can I change the channel or diagnose this problem?

I have read online somewhere it is possible the two xbee units have different version of firmware.  If this is the problem, how can I determine which version of firmware is installed on the two units?

The coordinator unit has version 20A7 and the router node has 22A7.

Is it possible this is the problem?

**UPDATE:**

coordinator profile:

```
XB24-ZB_20A7.mxi
80
0
251
20A7
0
[A]ID=100
[A]SC=FFFF
[A]SD=3
[A]ZS=0
[A]NJ=FF
[A]DH=13A200
[A]DL=408B81EE
[A]NI=COORDINATOR1
[A]NH=1E
[A]BH=0
[A]AR=FF
[A]DD=30000
[A]NT=3C
[A]NO=0
[A]CR=3
[A]SE=E8
[A]DE=E8
[A]CI=11
[A]PL=4
[A]PM=1
[A]EE=0
[A]EO=0
[A]BD=3
[A]NB=0
[A]SB=0
[A]RO=3
[A]D7=1
[A]D6=0
[A]CT=64
[A]GT=3E8
[A]CC=2B
[A]SP=20
[A]SN=1
[A]D0=1
[A]D1=0
[A]D2=0
[A]D3=0
[A]D4=0
[A]D5=1
[A]P0=1
[A]P1=0
[A]P2=0
[A]PR=1FFF
[A]LT=0
[A]RP=28
[A]DO=1
[A]IR=0
[A]IC=0
[A]V+=0
```

router profile

```
XB24-ZB_22A7.mxi
80
0
251
22A7
0
[A]ID=100
[A]SC=FFFF
[A]SD=3
[A]ZS=0
[A]NJ=FF
[A]NW=0
[A]JV=0
[A]JN=0
[A]DH=13A200
[A]DL=408B820C
[A]NI=ROUTER1
[A]NH=1E
[A]BH=0
[A]AR=FF
[A]DD=30000
[A]NT=3C
[A]NO=0
[A]CR=3
[A]SE=E8
[A]DE=E8
[A]CI=11
[A]PL=4
[A]PM=1
[A]EE=0
[A]EO=0
[A]BD=3
[A]NB=0
[A]SB=0
[A]RO=3
[A]D7=1
[A]D6=0
[A]CT=64
[A]GT=3E8
[A]CC=2B
[A]SM=0
[A]SN=1
[A]SO=0
[A]SP=20
[A]ST=1388
[A]PO=0
[A]D0=1
[A]D1=0
[A]D2=0
[A]D3=0
[A]D4=0
[A]D5=1
[A]P0=1
[A]P1=0
[A]P2=0
[A]PR=1FFF
[A]LT=0
[A]RP=28
[A]DO=1
[A]IR=0
[A]IC=0
[A]V+=0
```

Comment: Does X-CTU recognize the port, and does it respond to +++ from the terminal window? Does it give an error when you click [W]rite with your changes? Did you try checking the ALWAYS UPDATE FIRMWARE checkbox?

Comment: @RonJ- Yes. both xbees respond to +++, and I get an "OK"  back.  I also tried the other commands like ATVR, ATCH, etc..and they all return information correctly.  The problem is both xbees are on different channels so they can't see each other.  I believe the problem has to be mismatched firmware versions.  I want to upgrade the coordinator node to have 22A7, but it appears like digi's website is down.

Comment: @user1068636 "can't not"? XD

Comment: neonicotinoids?